# Using php session inside wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, session

I installed **plugin** for paypal payement, and it uses wordpress **session**.

Login page is **outside** wordpress in codeignitier, i want to use session what is defined outside wp inside wordpress. I can call it like 
`$_SESSION['key']` .

Plugin has some global variables like `$current_user` what is array with all user data.

Can i set session/cookie outside to be like is defined inside wordpress, or i can switch wordpress to use sessions defined outside ?

Comment: If it's in the same webserver, you can access it. After `session_start()` did you tried to var_dump $_SESSION to see it's structure and data?

Comment: @AlanMachado
When i dump $_SESSION there is only data i define outside wordpress. 
Wordpress using cookies, can i force him to use SESSION?

Comment: I wouldn't recommend such approach unless there are specific configs you can do within it to change that behavior. Never force-alter things inside framework because you risk to break the dependencies. If it's cookies what it uses, then cookies is what you might manipulate (if you can)

Comment: @AlanMachado Is there some "formula" how wordpress store user data? I share wordpress tables thought application, so i am using same table inside CI.

Comment: Sure there is, but I don't know since I do REST API direct implementations and work little with frameworks. The classes working with it might be described at WP docs